# Looking for MQTT broker and client recommendations

Tags: mqtt, communication, protocols

Working to make a network of remote sensors using MQTT I'm looking for an implementation of a broker an a matching client.

Requirements

- broker to be deployed in a cloud server like EC-2 and client to be deployed in a raspberry pi
- easy and quick to get started to allow the prototyping process to start as soon as possible
- complete documentation. Including getting started, general usability and advance issues like security
- projects with active communities to support the implementation with many people using it
- easy customization and usability
- to have a simple way to store the received data in a database using a client or with the broker
- client in python
- wide compatibility with hardware and with MQTT versions

I made some research and found Mosquitto and Paho but I would like you to suggest and give me some recommendations about them or another ones.

PD: Thanks to all that answer before recommending how to improve the question

Comment: Hi @Juan, this is a good edit to your question. Perhaps to make it even clearer, you could [edit] further to explain why Mosquitto and Paho didn't meet your needs? Then we'd know exactly what you need and will be able to reopen the question. Good luck.

Comment: @JuanPabloBecoña You still haven't said why mosquitto and paho don't meet your needs

Comment: I was looking for recommendations about clients and brokers. I continued working with mosquitto and paho and until now it's all right. I was specially asking about the size of their community, what were your opinions about them and if you think that were good options to cover the requirements.